# Trying to make websites load faster

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, preload

I've seen websites like YouTube and Gmail load fast. I know that Gmail is a Single Page App but YouTube is not, Is there a way to make a website that is not a SPA that can load this fast?

**NOTE:** I am using a static site

Comment: I think what you want is called "Single Page Application", like vue/angular: https://vuejs.org/ & https://angular.io/ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: I sure do use that but I also see the URL on the address bar changes... it is easy with javascript to do that...

Comment: Thats exaclty what a SPA is for. The url changing is called "routing". The reason why it is  so blazing fast is, thats its allready loaded but not shown. And if the url shows `/page` or `/page.html` is just what you prefer.

Comment: Think so... can you show me an example so I can see if it is what I need?

Comment: I linked you two frameworks with great documentation. Vue.js has live demos in ther docs: https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/ & https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/ Rightclick on the iframe and click "open in new tab" to see how the url changes. Vue is realy well documented and self explaining with copy and paste examples.

Comment: You can remove them and work with "history mode" to remove the # from the url. Thats just a setting ;)

Comment: Its a configuration option/practice in the routing mechanism of a SPA WebApp: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Just adjust you server config like in the description... There is a clear, forward solution for this in the links i provide. If you cant configure the server, ask a seperate question. There is no "I need this but cant do this" solution for you. I tell you what is possible and what not. In the end you need to decide how to proceed. The question(s) that follow, are off this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is pretty old now. I understand you need to use "hashtag urls" instead of direct ones. Direct ones can be shown as the address with `history.pushState`.
MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA

Example of a SPA App

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        if (document.location.href == 'https://example.com/#page'){
            history.pushState('', '', "https://example.com/page")
            document.querySelector("body").
        }
        // use 301 redirects to make sure the /page url (without hashtag) goes to the one with a hashtag.
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here prefetching is done like this:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/your/webpage/link.html">
```

Place the above in the header of your page for each page you want to prefetch.

Comment: The difference may be 2-5 ms. When you use sites that seem very fast, that is normally due to the site itself being fast, if your site is for example slow, prefetch may not be your solution. Creating fast sites is an art of itself. A site designed correctly can be significantly much faster. Almost seem instant. Their are various techniques that can be used to make links/pages in a site appear in a just a few ms. A good place to start is Google Lighthouse, speed test tool.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: I'd rather need something like when you click the link, the title changes, the body changes, and the address changes at once... doesn't take a second to load and it doesn't show the "loading favicon" at all

Comment: That effect is created by building what is termed as a one page app or  AMP https://developers.google.com/amp. These are two different concepts. You can make a site instant by building the site as a one page app in JavaScript.

Comment: I will check out amp... I tried it once but I'm not sure it worked

Comment: You can produce very fast sites using the right HTML design, low overhead on files, fast servers such as Netlify.com, and below page view loading. If the site needs to be indexed this has the added value or improved SEO, a one page site may be harder, not impossible to SEO as well.

Comment: I have been using Netlify, and have tested my site on Lighthouse, It isn't slow but I was thinking of making a fast-loading site like YouTube, the site is not a SPA but it still does not reload. I'm interested in making something like YouTube's loader.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clearly. You are must be focus what is your problem? Or what is your concern? Etc... Because to talking about page load faster, it is not mean SPA is faster to other technology. Its depending by your technical, system, application, networks, database, etc... A tons issue to reference to performance of the pages. Maybe security is impact to performance, hard disk of sever to slow to serve the service, workloads of framework, etc...